# What's the best way performance-wise to SELECT from a PARTITIONed table in MySQL: explicit partition selection, pruning with a WHERE clause, or both?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Say you have:

```
CREATE TABLE  demo (
    amount ,
    year ,
    cycle ,
    otherStuff ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id , year , cycle )
) ENGINE = INNODB
PARTITION BY RANGE ( year )
SUBPARTITION BY KEY ( cycle ) 
SUBPARTITIONS 12 (
    PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN (2021) ,
    PARTITION p2021 VALUES LESS THAN (2022) ,
    PARTITION p2022 VALUES LESS THAN (2023) ,
    PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

What's the best SELECT to run on that table?

A:

```
SELECT otherStuff FROM demo WHERE amount > 10 AND year = 2022 AND cycle = 1;
```

B:

```
SELECT otherStuff FROM demo (p2022, p1) WHERE amount > 10;
```

or

C:

```
SELECT otherStuff FROM demo (p2022, p1) WHERE amount > 10 AND year = 2022 AND cycle = 1;
```

I'm sure that there is some extra overhead in pruning—some preliminary step for the storage engine to take to figure out which partitions match the WHERE clause. But, where only one partition and subpartition match the WHERE clause and the pruning WHERE clause contains only simple equals comparisons, what I'm trying to figure out is whether the extra overhead is nominal for performance. The reason I want to figure that out is because I want to know if I can get away with pruning, which offers an advantage in design: if I ever wanted to, I could get rid of my partitions and have no queries to change. In other words, explicit partition selection introduces a dependency I'd rather avoid.

Thanks.

Comment: (You changed `id` in some places, but missed the PK.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above.  That is, "A", but without any partitioning.

Get rid of partitioning unless you can show some use for it.

Only in certain applications does `PARTITON` help with performance.  I have never found a performance use for `SUBPARTITION`.

**WHERE amount > 10 AND year = 2022 AND cycle = 1**

That is best handled by

```
INDEX(year, cycle,  -- in either order
      amount)       -- put 'range' after '='
```

Partitioning would not help *this* query.

**Time Series**

A "time series" can be stored in a partitioned table where each partition is a week or month (or other time range).  However, the only advantage comes when you get ready to Delete or Archive "old" rows.

`DROP PARTITION` is *much* faster and less invasive than the equivalent `DELETE`.  However, it assumes that the oldest "week" can be jettisoned entirely.

Meanwhile, there is *no* performance benefit to `SELECTs`.  Think of it this way.  Partition pruning will pick (perhaps) one partition to look in, then the index takes over.  But pruning is not "free".  Nor is walking down a BTree.  The BTree *might* be one level shallower because the partitioning serves for one level of "tree".  But that just implies that the `SELECT` is trading off one search mechanism for another -- possibly without any performance change.

More on time series and how to Partition for such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint  That also covers how to efficiently create the 'next' partition as time goes on.

If you don't want to `DROP` the old partition, but want to "archive" it, then partitioning facilitates "transportable tablespaces", where the partition is removed from the main table and turned into a table by itself.  Then that can be 'transported' to somewhere else.  Again, that only applies to a complete partition, hence the rows being moved must align with the `PARTITION BY ...` being used.

**Other uses for Partitioning**

See the above link; I have found only 4 other cases; they are more obscure than Time Series.

**Covering indexes**

Indexing is too complex to make many general statements.  If the covering index has two columns that are both being tested with a range (eg, `BETWEEN`), the query is destined to be inefficient.  Essentially a BTree index can deal with only one range.  This leads to a rarely seen use for Partitioning -- use partition pruning for one "range" and an Index for the other.

Finding "nearby" places on a globe can use that two-dimensional lookup with `PARTITION BY RANGE(latitude)` with `longitude` in the index.

I don't see this trick being viable beyond 2 ranges.

Back to "covering"...  If the `WHERE` clause using a covering index has multiple ranges, there are still performance issues.

Another thing about "covering" indexes -- sometimes they are unwieldy because of having "too many" columns.  I use the Rule of Thumb that says "don't put more than 5 columns in an `INDEX`".  (This is a very soft rule; there is nothing magical about "5".)

**Optimal index(es)**

We can discuss one query at a time, but that is not sufficient.  A table is usually hit by many different Selects.  To find the optimal indexes, we need to see all the main queries at once.

If one Select begs for `INDEX(a)` and another begs for `INDEX(a,b)`, having both indexes is counterproductive.  It is better to get rid of the shorter one.

My recommendation above suggests either `(year, cycle, amount)` or `(cycle, year, amount)`.  Possibly *another* query would pick between them.  Or, maybe there is enough variety in the queries to require *both* variations.

More on indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: This is pseudocode. The idea was simply to isolate the difference between pruning and explicit selection. I certainly can be talked out of partitioning, but it's a time-series partition scheme, and it seems reasonable to create new partitions as time goes along as I anticipate a lot of data. Data from expired time series will just be archived and dropped.

The actual database has indexes for every query. As far as 'id," guess you're right. Makes little sense that way. There's actually a property I search on. I'm editing accordingly.

Comment: I think I've heard before that B-tree indexes are like partitions anyway. Is it possible that, where there's a covering index for every query, partitions are 100% useless no matter how large the tables are?

Comment: @JackAdder999 - I did a major overhaul of my Answer.